# Cut numpy matrix rows with upper and lower limit in python without pandas

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Suppose I have some numpy matrix N x M where the column 0 is time, and that I want to select all the rows (which will be consecutive) for which the time value t is such that tmin < t < tmax. I would like to do it without using Pandas, and avoiding loops.

I have tried something like:

```
data = data[ tmin < data[:, 0] <=tmax]
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

On the other side, if I do the following:

```
data = data[ data[:, 0] <=tmax]
```

then I obtain the correct result. Can somebody please explain to me how could I write the first line of code in a similar compact (pythonic) way, but avoiding the value error? I am not sure how to use the .any() or .all() functions to obtain what I need.
I have also seen the numpy.clip function, but that doesn't cut the rows with time values outside the boundaries, it only substitutes these values with (tmin, tmax).

Comment: That `a<x<b` syntax only works for Python scalars; it actually uses shortcutting  `and` and thus does not work with numpy arrays (which have multiple True/False values).  Same problem when using `if x<b:` expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use numpy [bitwise_and](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html#numpy.bitwise_and) (or the *&* operator as shorthand)

```
np.random.seed(2021)
a = np.random.choice(10, (6,6))
print(a)
[[4 5 9 0 6 5]
 [8 6 6 6 6 1]
 [5 7 1 1 5 2]
 [0 3 1 0 2 6]
 [4 8 5 1 6 7]
 [5 6 9 5 6 9]]
tmin = 0
tmax = 5
a[(a[:, 0] > tmin) & (a[:, 0] <= tmax)]
array([[4, 5, 9, 0, 6, 5],
       [5, 7, 1, 1, 5, 2],
       [4, 8, 5, 1, 6, 7],
       [5, 6, 9, 5, 6, 9]])
```